# How to change ImageView resource in nested listview items?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

[image]

I have a listview which have a imageview and some textview.  How can I change imageview resource if I click on a image.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Are you trying to change that same image you clicking?

Comment: Also we will not provide a full solution for you. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: exactly. When i click on any image it will change to another

Comment: it's hard without showing us some code , basicaly in the adapter you do onclick on item and change the image , show your adapter

Comment: i add onclick listener on imageview but when i click on a image two and more images resources also change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your logic, you need to:

- Set onItemClickListener
- save the position selected inside the listener
- set onClickListener of the images inside the adapter
- use the position selected to recover the imagem from the data saved in the adapter

Código setOnItemClickListener:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        lastSelectedItem = position;
        // Set the collor of the backgroud of the row in the listView, remmember to test if the flag already have been initialized;
    }
});
```

Código setOnClickListener:

```
onClick(View v){
    // use some field thought the constructor of the adapter
    Drawable draw = data.getImage(lastSelectedItem);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) v;
    img.setDrawable(draw);
    // set the lastSelectedItem and change the color of the background
}
```

I hope that help you.